# Create a list with entries in specific columns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list with entries in the second column to the last column of a csv file.

```
import csv
with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     table = [row for row in reader]

col_2_and_rest = [row[1:] for row in table]
```

I am currently getting lists in a list, which is not what I want; I only want a single list. Is there a method for this?

Comment: Please add some examples & sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
import csv
with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     table = [row for row in reader]

col_2_and_rest = sum([row[1:] for row in table], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.reduce`:

```
import csv
from functools import reduce
from operator import iconcat

with open("csv.csv") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     table = [row for row in reader]

col_2_and_rest = reduce(iconcat, [row[1:] for row in table])
```